# Webtrends: Combine sub domains report in one report

Tags: webtrends

I'm new to webtrends, am using webtrends to track page using meta tag.
I have coupeles of subdomains like

```
www.us.example.com
www.eu.example.com
www.uk.example.com
```

So now a particular page xyz.php is showing three times using different subdomains.
I want to combine all the three subdomain to one report.

Can anybody help me out?

A big thank you in advance.
Uttam

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple of options:

1) You can use URL Search and Replace to change the url.

2) If you want a separate report for just those urls and want to display the url without changing it, you could create a Hit Filter and apply the hit filter to the report.

Comment: Could you expand your answer and explain how?

Comment: I went to Web Analysis -> Report Configuration -> URL Search and Replace.  I configure it with Replace From = Start of first with a value of "eu", Up To = Start of next with value of "." and With = "us".  I entered "www.eu.example.com" in the Test Area box, hit Test and got "www.us.example.com."  I am not sure if you can use regular expressions here so you might need to have a different search and replace item for each url.  This will cause all of those hits to have the same url, which may not be what you want.

Comment: If you want a separate report for just those urls and want to display the url without changing it, you could create a Hit Filter and apply the hit filter to the report.  That might actually be a better idea than my first suggestion.

Comment: Good information - you can always edit additional information into your original answer (for improved presentation and layout).

Comment: Thanks, I forgot you could edit your responses.  I edited my original response.